# Simulate click on valums Ajax Uploader

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I'm having trouble getting jQuery's 'click()' to work in Valums Ajax Uploader button.

I need to simulate the button click from code, but seems that this plugin doesn't use click to launch the file explorer. The selector is correct and there's no JavaScript error, but I just can't get the thing to work.

Tried with `trigger` and `live` also, with identical result.

This is the call:

```
$("div[class='qq-upload-button']").click();
```

Am I calling the wrong event?

Answer (score 1):

Divs don't have click events. Instead of div, you have to call the click event of the button with such a code.

```
document.getElementById('btnUpload').click();
```

However, the button generated by Valums Ajax Uploader doesn't have an id or a class. You have to add an id attribute by editing valums script (fileuploader.js). Simply find the line `input.setAttribute("type", "file");` in the javascript file and insert `input.setAttribute("id", "btnUpload");` under it.

Comment: No need to add id, you can simply link it to the input inside main div that already has your ID. 

I'll use jQuery to demonstrate ... 
 $('#uploadElementID input').trigger('click');

where #uploadElementID is element property with which you set up FileUploader.

Comment: @sevenkul: Nice solution. This worked perfectly for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to find the function called on click, and call it manually.

Comment: I've readed the plugin source code, and there's no click binding (I think). What other possibilities are there to listen to click events without using click?